# Stopping unnecessary button form submits html js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This may be too short and sweet, but this is all I have to ask. When I have two buttons in HTML, I use one button for form submission, and another to trigger a javascript event. However, what is happening is that both buttons perform form submits. I want to use the other button for submits without making it unusable by javascript. WHat are the possible methods I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Saravanan Sachi and aladin8848 already said:

If you are using `<input>` for your buttons, `type="submit"` will always submit your form and `type="button"` will be a plain, non-form submitting button.

If though you are using `<button></button>` tags for your buttons (as I tend to do), they have a 'default' type of submit, so you have to explicitly set their type to button ex. `<button type="button">Do JS click things</button>` to prevent it from submitting your form.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<input type="submit">
```

to submit the form and

```
<input type="button">
```

to call JavaScript method

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input type='button' onclick='....'>
```

instead of what you are probably using

```
<input type='submit'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the next:

```
var buttonList = document.getElelmentsByTagName('button');

buttonList[2].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.removeEventListener("click", this, false);
    //do something, like add your own event
});
```

you should be more specific getting the buttons, and i don't test the code, but the idea is that, remove events and default behaviour of the second button.

i hope this helps you.